# vb.net listview display next record

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have a problem when displaying the records in ListView. The database I have right now have a 10k + of records (rows). When pulling the data to ListView, It takes a lot of time so I limit the displayed items to 50. I can successfully display the 50 items. But my problem is how do I display the next 51-100 record when the user click the "Next Page" button? I have no idea where to start. Please help me. Thanks.

```
    da = New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim strSql As String = "SELECT * FROM tbl_questions"
    ListView1.Items.Clear()

    Call connect()

    da.SelectCommand = New MySqlCommand(strSql)
    da.SelectCommand.Connection = cn
    da.Fill(ds)

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1 

        If i = 49 Then
            Exit For
        End If

        Dim lv As ListViewItem = ListView1.Items.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("function"))
        lv.SubItems.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("subject"))
        lv.SubItems.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("level"))
        lv.SubItems.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("type"))
        lv.SubItems.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("question"))
        lv.SubItems.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("choice_a"))
        lv.SubItems.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("choice_b"))
        lv.SubItems.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("choice_c"))
        lv.SubItems.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("choice_d"))
        lv.SubItems.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("correct_ans"))

    Next
    da.Dispose()
```

Comment: A DataGridView would be **much** better suited for this.  You could simply bind it to the data source and it would populate itself.

Comment: ...and another thing ;)  The way you have it you are making copies of the data to show in the LV.  Bind the DataTable to a DGV and the data stays there, no copies, it simply shows in the DGV.

Comment: can you give me some example? Im not really familiar in datagridview since I always use listview. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using winforms. The ListView control does have a virtualization feature that you can try by using the [`ListView.VirtualMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode(v=vs.110).aspx) Property and [`ListView.CacheVirtualItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.cachevirtualitems(v=vs.110).aspx) Event. See if these MSDN links help you.

From above link:

> Virtual mode can be useful under many circumstances. If a ListView object must be populated from a very large collection already in memory, creating a ListViewItem object for each entry can be wasteful. In virtual mode, only the items required are created. In other cases, the values of the ListViewItem objects may need to be recalculated frequently, and doing this for the whole collection would produce unacceptable performance. In virtual mode, only the required items are calculated.